# Aggregating data with different categories of a column in R

Tags: r, count, aggregate

I am working on this data where a list of students (**ID**) are linked to their favourite sports which can be chosen only from 7 different sports . For one unique ID there may be more than one favourite sport. The following is a snapshot of it.

```
 ID    Sports
  1    Soccer
  2    Basketball
  3    Tennis
  1    Basketball
  4    Soccer
  2    Hockey
  3    Basketball
  5    Soccer
  6    Rafting
  2    surfing
  1    Hockey
  6    Soccer
  7    Tennis
```

I need to create a data that shows count of how many different sports each student (ID) like and also show those sports, some outcome as follows:

```
 ID           count                  All Favourite Sports
 1               3                   Soccer, Basketball,Hockey 
 2               3                   Basketball,Hockey,surfing
 3               2                   Tennis, Basketball
 4               1                   Soccer  
 5               1                   Soccer
 6               2                   Rafting, Soccer
 7               1                   Tennis
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this task using the `dplyr` package and the following code. Please note, `data` should be the name of your data.frame in your question:

```
> data %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
+     summarize(count = n_distinct(Sports),
+               all_sports = toString(Sports)) %>%
+     ungroup()

# A tibble: 7 x 3
     ID count all_sports                 
  <int> <int> <chr>                      
1     1     3 Soccer, Basketball, Hockey 
2     2     3 Basketball, Hockey, surfing
3     3     2 Tennis, Basketball         
4     4     1 Soccer                     
5     5     1 Soccer                     
6     6     2 Rafting, Soccer            
7     7     1 Tennis
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can try

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  transmute(ID, count = n(), `All Favourite Sports` = paste(unique(Sports), collapse = ", ")) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  ungroup()

#       ID count `All Favourite Sports`     
#     <int> <int> <chr>                      
# 1     1     3   Soccer, Basketball, Hockey 
# 2     2     3   Basketball, Hockey, surfing
# 3     3     2   Tennis, Basketball         
# 4     4     1   Soccer                     
# 5     5     1   Soccer                     
# 6     6     2   Rafting, Soccer            
# 7     7     1   Tennis
```